# Escape key re-opens Ctrl+P in Vim

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I started using Ctrl+P with Vim a couple months ago. In the documentation, it says that escape should exit the Ctrl+P search mode, which I like. However, there is also undocumented (that I can find) functionality such that pressing the escape key when already in command mode re-opens the Ctrl+P search mode. This is terrible for me as I often hit escape multiple times or use it to just verify I'm in command mode. Is there some way to disable this functionality?

Comment: What's the result of running `:echo g:ctrlp_map`?

Comment: curious why you are hitting the apple modifier with `Esc`. what vim are you using? terminal? gvim? mvim? nvim? If you are using Vim which version?

Comment: This behavior is probably a result of some strange mapping, not a "feature" of Ctrl+P. Low hanging fruit, but try entering `nmap ^[` (hit ctrl-v and then escape) in the ex command line to see if escape is mapped to something weird.

Comment: To answer all your questions:

The result of `echo g:ctrlp_map` is `<c-p>`.

I am not hitting the Apple modifier with escape. I'm using gvim on windows, Vim 7.3.

Entering `nmap ^[` on the command prompt says "No Mapping Found".

Answer (score 0):

Dylan MacKenzie's answer tipped me off to the problem since it explicitly referenced the `[` character. I had mapped Ctrl+[ to bring up Ctrl+P for search on existing buffers. I guess this is an overload for the escape key, which was causing the problem.

Comment: `<c-[>` is `<esc>` its not an overload.